# realloc of array struct in other struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, realloc

My problem is in the line when I call realloc(), but works with the first "Elemento"
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
typedef struct{
   string palabra;
   string* significados;
   size_t tam;
} Elemento;

typedef struct{
   Elemento* elementos;
   size_t tam;
} Diccionario;

Diccionario crearDic(){
   Diccionario dic;
   dic.tam = 0;
   return dic;
}

void agregarPalabraDic(Diccionario &dic, string pal, string sig){   
   dic.elementos = (Elemento*)realloc(dic.elementos,(dic.tam+1)*sizeof(Elemento));
   dic.tam++;

   dic.elementos[dic.tam-1].palabra = pal;   
   dic.elementos[dic.tam-1].significados = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string));    
   dic.elementos[dic.tam-1].tam = 1; 
   dic.elementos[dic.tam-1].significados[0] = sig; 
}
```

And here is the main() :

```
int main(){
   Diccionario dic = crearDic();
   agregarPalabraDic(dic,"apple","red"); //no problem here
   agregarPalabraDic(dic,"banana","yellow"); //thats the problem
   ...
}
```

I have days trying and nothing, i need some help.. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root of your problems is manual memory management. Since this is C++ you do not really need to do all of that. The best solutions is to replace:

```
typedef struct
{
   std::string palabra;
   std::string* significados;
   size_t tam;
} Elemento;

typedef struct
{
   Elemento* elementos;
   size_t tam;
} Diccionario;
```

with:

```
typedef struct
{
   std::string palabra;
   std::vector<string>significados;
   size_t tam;
} Elemento;

typedef struct
{
   std::vector<Elemento> elementos;
   size_t tam;
} Diccionario;
```

Once you do that your program should be much more easier and less prone to errors.

Comment: right.. but is easy with STL, i wanna an other solution without STL or only C

Comment: @RobertoCuadros: Make up your mind, Do you want a C++ program ora  C program? You cannot tell us you want to write a program in C++ and then expect to get a solution in C. You are already using `std::string` So I don't see why using a `std::vector` should be a problem.

Comment: ty very much,  u right, i just trying TAD's.. i changed string to char* and string* to  char** and finally is ok

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
Diccionario crearDic(){
   Diccionario dic;
   dic.tam = 0;
   return dic;
}
```

Why are you returning dic which was created on stack. You should create it on heap and then return.

Or else the object will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: The object is returned by value, so there is no problem.